# Pygame platforms don't move evenly when scroll speed is increased

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pygame program that creates platforms on a screen. These platforms should be evenly spaced out across the y axis of the screen. The platforms have a random gap in them such that a player can jump through the platform. The platforms move down because of a scroll variable. In order to make the game more exciting, I want to increase the speed of the scrolling. I do this by incrementing the scroll variable by 0.25 every 10 seconds. However, then a bug arises where every time the scroll variable gets incremented, the distance between the gaps increases.

I set the variable for the platforms as itself to -200 for the next platform, but I still got bigger gaps when the scroll variable increments.

```
class platformclassleft(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, y, width):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(platform_image, (width, 50))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y

def update(self, scroll):
    self.rect.y += scroll

    if self.rect.top > 900:
        self.kill()

class platformclassright(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, x, y, width):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(platform_image, (width, 50))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y

def update(self, scroll):
    self.rect.y += scroll

    if self.rect.top > SCREENSIZEY:
        self.kill()

def gettimefunc():
global scrolling, starttime, scroll, gameplayscroll, increment, gameplayheight, incremented
while scrolling == True:
        elapsedtime = time.perf_counter() - starttime
        elapsedtime = int(elapsedtime)
        gameplayscroll += increment
        if abs(gameplayscroll) >= 836:
            gameplayscroll = 0
        if elapsedtime == 10:
            scroll += 0.25
            increment += 0.25
            incremented = True
            starttime = time.perf_counter()
            starttime = int(starttime)
            return incremented
        else: 
            incremented = False
            return incremented

if len(platformgroupleft) < MAX_PLATFORMS:
    platformwidthleft = random.randint(0, 1250)
    platformwidthright = SCREENSIZEX - platformwidthleft
    if platformwidthleft == 0:
        platformleftx = 150
    else:
        platformleftx = 0
    if platformwidthright == 0:
        platformrightx = 1350
    else:
        platformrightx = platformwidthleft + 150
    platformleft = platformclassleft(platformleftx, platformsy, platformwidthleft)
    platformright = platformclassright(platformrightx, platformsy, platformwidthright)
    platformgroupleft.add(platformleft)
    platformgroupright.add(platformright)
    print(incremented)
    platformsy -= 200
```

Comment: Could you please add your code as a minimal reproducible example, properly formatted in code blocks? It is not possible for us to find an issue in code that we don't have.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in spawning the new platform.

Let's say that:

- You spawn new platform
- then you move it down
- spawn another platform after some time
- move it down
- repeat.

**The problem is that the speed increases, but platform spawn rate doesn't so the platform will rather fall before the new one will spawn.**
The answer is to change the spawn rate with the speed of the platform.